# How to use a session variable or cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a main page with a large list of companies, I have a search button and if I want to find a company by state or city I can filter my search.

I decide to filter my search by cities,  lets say Chicago, and I get 10 companies as a result of my search.

I click any company in that list and I go to the company details but I realize that is not the one I am looking for, so I want to go back to my 10 companies result list but instead I go back to the main company search interface and I have to re-start my search again.

How to use a session variable or cookies for this case?

Somebody can help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Another valid option not involving `Session` or `cookies` would be using the url for passing search parameters. If your site is public this may also help you with SEO.

You could use a friendly url + rewriting rules or just querystring if you are not using any rewriting.

On the company details page you'd store the referrer url and if the user wants to come back, you do it to that page.

Comment: Hi Claudio
Let me tell you more about this.  Is a page for internal porposes for the company that I work for.

So as I said before, once they want to go back clicking the menu bar or the back button they want to go back to the list results in order to DONT do the search again.

Comment: If you think about how google goes a search, I want to search for the word hello you can just go to this link https://www.google.com/search?q=Hello so it picks up the query string and does the search

Comment: How does this looks:
session["searchResults"] = searchList

 searchList = trim(lcase(Session(""searchResults")))

Comment: @AntonioArredondo: what is `searchList`?

Comment: I just assigned as a variable.

As you can see I am a entry level programer, but they are asking me to perform this task, and is any IT people in the company but me.

Thanks for the patient

Comment: @Antonio Arredondo: I'd need to see that code in the context of the rest of the logic but if `searchList` contains the search terms that could work.

Comment: @Claudio Redi  protected void search_button_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        SearchType = 1;
        gvCompanyList.PageIndex = 0;
        SearchForCompanies();
       
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)  
        {          
            string filter = Session["SearchQuery"].ToString(); 
            if(filter  != null)         
            {             
            FilterResults(filter)         
            }  
        }   
this is all what I have in my search button

Comment: @Antonio Arredondo: test it and come with feedback from it :)

Comment: @Claudio Redi  I just test it and doesnt show me any error, but is not working, Once I set my filter selection lets said, state of New York it display all my companies located in the New York State and if I pick any of those results, its display it properly, but then if I go back, my New York list disappear and I have to start all over again. As I said no error in my screen but doesnt works

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Claudio, but if you do want to use session I would do something like the following

In page load do something like this

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack) 
{

        string filter = Session["SearchQuery"].ToString();
        if(filter  != null)
        {
            FilterResults(filter)
        } 
}
```

And then in your filter event do something like

```
Session["Filter"] = txtCityName.txt;
FilterResults(txtCityName.txt);
```